# I cannot get Java JMX server to bind to 127.0.0.1 only!

Tags: java, jmx

I have a java server. I want to be able to connect to it with a JMX client. 
I do this:

```
JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(null,null,JMX_PORT);
JMXConnectorServer jmxRemoteServer;
jmxRemoteServer=JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(jmxUrl, jmxEnvironment, server);
jmxRemoteServer.start();
```

This works. I can fire up JConsole and connect to JMX_PORT on my machine and pretty graphs show up.

There is a problem. This causes the JMX server to bind to JMX_PORT on all interfaces. I want to have it bind to 127.0.0.1 only. Otherwise, it is a security concern for me.

According to the documentation, `JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(null,null,config.getJmxRemotePort());` should create a JMXServiceURL with the default protocol (jmxmp) and localhost. I have tried giving it "127.0.0.1" explicitely as an address to bind to, and it did not work either.

Java's JMX server binds to all IP addresses, and refuses to bind to 127.0.0.1 only.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, all my research led me to believe it is not possible to bind JMX to just one particular IP address. It binds to them all.

Comment: Seems that -Djmx.remote.server.address.wildcard=false might do the trick of forcing it to bind to one IP address: http://blog.markfeeney.com/2010/10/jmx-through-ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: If you are using RMI as your protocol, please refer to this URL : http://dev.303.se/development/95/limiting-rmi-to-127-0-0-1/

Comment: this is not the correct answer.  -Djmx.remote.server.address.wildcard=false causes JMX to bind only to the address it is given.

Comment: for which version of the JVM is this, and on which platform? This may be very useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
    InetAddress local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Host address: " + local.getHostAddress());
    System.out.println("Host name: " + local.getHostName());
    System.out.println("Canonical host name: " + local.getCanonicalHostName());
    System.out.println("Address: " + local.getAddress());
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

If you pass `null` as the host argument the class uses `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`. For me at least it doesn't return "127.0.0.1", it uses my machine's name, which actually seems wrong based on the description (this is not my loopback address). That address is useable by other machines. What happens when you try:

```
JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL("http","127.0.0.1",JMX_PORT);
```

or:

```
JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(null,"127.0.0.1",JMX_PORT);
```

If not supplied, the protocol defaults to "jmxmp".

Comment: @cletus - my reading of the javadoc for `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` is that the method returns the local machine's hostname/IP normally, and only returns the loopback IP if the security manager says "No!".

Comment: @Stephen: that would be my reading too but run the little program I pasted above. It's returning the machine's name and DHCP address not the loopback address.

Comment: you misunderstand me.  I'm saying that I'd NOT expect it to return the loopback address ... normally!  Otherwise, why would the javadoc include the last sentence about the loopback address at all?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, as providing "127.0.0.1" as the second parameter to the JMXServiceURL constructor also results in JMX binding to all available interfaces. I have mitigated this y filtering the port in iptables, but would feel more comfortable if JMX was not bound to the port on the public interface in the first place.